# Encoding numeric nominal values in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, data-processing

I am working on a network data based machine learning problem where one of the columns in my dataset is `Destination Port` where the values are like `30, 80, 1024, etc.`.

Since the numeric values in this column are not ordinal, how do I transform this column in some way so that I can put it as an input to the machine learning model? The column has about 480 unique ports.

Answer (score 2):

it's called normalization and the goal of normalization is to change the values of numeric columns in the dataset to use a common scale, without distorting differences in the ranges of values or losing information.

```
 # Create x, where x the 'scores' column's values as floats
 x = df[['name_of_ur_column']].values.astype(float)

 # Create a minimum and maximum processor object
 min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()

 # Create an object to transform the data to fit minmax processor
 x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
```

or you can use the original format

```
 # Run the normalizer on the dataframe

 df_normalized = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled)
 normalized_df=(df-df.mean())/df.std()
```

to use min-max normalization:

```
 normalized_df=(df-df.min())/(df.max()-df.min())
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `Destination Port` is a Nominal feature, it can be encoded either using [label encoding](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) or [one hot encoding](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html).

**Label encoding**

Advantage: No increase in dimension
Disadvantage: Can have an ordinal effect on the model

**One hot encoding**

Advantage: No ordinal effect on model
Disadvantage: Increase in dimension